# Google Maps Javascript API request denied when using divi builders map module

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-maps, builder

I'm creating a wordpress site with elegant themes divi builder.

I'm trying to use the map module. I have uploaded my api key but its not displaying a map. When I try and enter an address I'm getting: mysite.net says: REQUEST_DENIED

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery.It is work for me:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY"></script>
jQuery('#googlemaps').gMap({
                maptype: 'ROADMAP',
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 13,
                markers: [
                    {
                        address: 'Ahmedabad, India', // Your Adress Here
                        html: '',
                        popup: false,
                    }

                ],

            });
```